# onclick firing twice and remove "attributes"

Tags: javascript

I have a form. In here dropdown for select rule type.according to rule type in below it displays rule attribute.user must select attributes. If the user wants to remove some attribute from it there is a close button.

```
<div class="desc" id="{{uuid}}" style="font-weight: 600" >{{name}}'+
'<button type=\'button\' aria-label=\'Close\' class=\'close\' id=\'{{uuid}}\' onclick=\'$(this).on("click",function() { $(this).parent().remove();alert("lllll"); })\'>X</button>' +
        '</div>'
```

when I used this code, then the user must click the close button twice to remove that selected attribute. how can I stop it firing twice?

Answer (score 1):

Your `onclick` event binds another `onclick` event that binds the button to remove on next click, so the `onclick` attribute should just be

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Hello from div
  <button id="{{uuid}}">X</button>
<div>
<script>
  $("#{{uuid}}").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    alert( this.id ); //Alert button ID
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I also want to pass that button id to another function.with this I can't do it..can you suggest something for that?

Comment: my button id is id=\'{{uuid}}\'. I have no idea how to pass this to function.it generate when user select attribute.

Comment: @SashaAlex I've placed it in `script` block